# Console-only virtual keyboard

Tags: keyboard, touch-screen

I'm setting up Linux on a tablet pc. Is there a virtual keyboard for the console? I want an input method for emergency cases, when X Window cannot be used and no wired keyboard is available. I'm on Arch Linux with kernel 4.10.9-1, so the touch input drivers are in the kernel and working properly at boot time.